# How to discover the size of a formatted string

Tags: c, string, memory-management

How can I discover the total size of a string after being formatted?

For example:

`"<xml id=\"%d\">%s</xml>"`

I need to allocate a string to call `sprintf` or `snprintf` to fill in that string, but I dont want to assume a value, like 4096 or some other fixed value.

How can I discover the total size of a string after being formatted?

For example:

`"<xml id=\"%d\">%s</xml>"`

I need to allocate a string to call `sprintf` or `snprintf` to fill in that string, but I dont want to assume a value, like 4096 or some other fixed value.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by calling `snprintf` two times.

The first time, we call it passing NULL as the buffer and zero as size:

```c
int size = snprintf(NULL, 0, "<xml id=\"%d\">%s</xml>", report_id, report_content) + 1;
```

It's very important to have that `+1` at the end, because we need to account for the `\0` character at the end of the string

Now we can allocate the buffer with the correct size:

```c
char *buffer = malloc(size * sizeof *buffer);
```

Now, finally, we call `snprintf` with the buffer we created:

```c
snprintf(buffer, size, "<xml id=\"%d\">%s</xml>", report_id, report_content);
```

It is also very important to use the same string and parameters in both calls to `snprintf`

Comment: `* sizeof(buffer)` is both wrong and pointless. You mean `sizeof( *buffer )`. In this case, `buffer` is a pointer to `char` so, by definition, `sizeof(char)` will always be `1`... Wrong and pointless... Additionally, accounting for the trailing NUL would be more visible as `... = malloc( size + 1 );`

Comment: Better to use `size += 1; // plus NUL` as a separate statement. Don't want to trim the end when `size` is used again in 2nd `snprintf()` (that could be the simpler `sprintf()` and skip the whole business anyway...)

Comment: As previously pointed out, `sizeof(buffer)` is wrong. Since `buffer` is of type `char *`, this will give you the size of a pointer, which is `8` bytes on most PC platforms. Multiplaying with the value `8` does not make sense. (EDIT: Meanwhile, someone else has fixed it.) However, in contrast to the comment by someone else, I find it ok to simply do `+1` when initializing the variable `size`.

Comment: @Fe2O3: Once corrected to `size * sizeof *buffer`, that is correct and good practice. Omitting `sizeof *buffer` because it is 1 is similar to the problem of using “magic numbers” in code—it uses a fixed value, does not explain to the reader, and breaks when the reason for the value changes. For example, a reasonable change to a program is to change `char` to `wchar_t` and make corresponding edits. But since there is no code for `* sizeof *buffer` since you would have removed it, it can easily be overlooked that the “no code” at that point needs to change.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If the programmer is sloppy, making changes willy-nilly, then they deserve to reap the appropriate rewards.

Comment: @Fe2O3: That is a naïve view. Humans make mistakes, it is impossible to prevent that completely, and good programming practice aims to avoid bugs by reducing opportunities for errors and designing code to be easier to maintain. Further, there is no benefit to omitting `* sizeof *buffer` as, if the size is 1, the compiler will omit it, thus costing nothing in executable size or execution time. Conversely, there is benefit in keeping it, so that is the better decision.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Upon consideration, shouldn't `size` be accounting for the larger `wchar_t` that is needed? Honest ignorance on my part...

Comment: @Fe2O3: `swprintf` returns a number of wide characters, not a number of bytes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks... :-) No experience with wide characters. Still think that the coder making a change from `char` to `wchar_t` would be better served by my second suggestion "Use `size += 1;` to avoid burying the `+1` at the end of `snprintf()` or in the `malloc()` argument. ("off by one" error appeared in a recent SO answer that attempted this "measure/allocate/assign" sequence. Life is fraught with peril!)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks for the comments and corrections, I had copied the "sizeof" expresion from somewhere else and in fact it is `sizeof *buffer`.